# Check that system passes all the states

Tags: tla+

A variable `state` stands for state of a system, for instance `state \in {"ready", "prepare", "do", "cleanup", "done"}`. How to express condition that `state` should eventually pass all the five states (in any order)?

---

Working example (accepted answer):

```
EXTENDS Naturals
VARIABLE n
Init == n = 1
Next == IF n < 3 THEN n' = n + 1 ELSE n' = n
Spec == Init /\ [][Next]_<<n>> /\ WF_<<n>>(Next)
Check == \A s \in {1,2,3}: <>(s = n)    \* This goes: Model Overview >
                                        \* > "What to check?" > Properties
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given `States = {"ready", "prepare", "do", "cleanup", "done"}`, you can check that it reaches some given state with

```
<>(state = "ready")
```

And you can check that it reaches all states with

```
\A s \in States: <>(state = s)
```